# Is it possible that $\mathsf{L} = \mathsf{NP}$?

Tags: complexity-theory

When I studied computer science 10 years ago, it was still an open question whether $\mathsf{L}$ and $\mathsf{NP}$ are truly different classes. Is that still the case or has the inequality been proven in the meantime?

(I know this is a somewhat stupid question, but there's nothing about it in the complexity zoo, and googling L and NP is surprisingly ineffective ;-))

Comment: https://books.google.co.il/books?id=7z3VCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=separating+L+and+np&source=bl&ots=WOweGBRaxl&sig=54a1OR5xQAbC5ueMPXfV6ZyR10M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvm5vg9sTMAhXC8RQKHQF4BwYQ6AEIJDAC#v=onepage&q=separating%20L%20and%20np&f=false

You can check out the paragraph about separating $L, NP$ here (section 3 in the linked page).

Comment: Possible, but unlikely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$L \subseteq NL \subseteq P \subseteq NP \subseteq PSPACE \subseteq EXP$

From space hierarchy and time hierarchy theorems we can prove that

$L \subsetneq PSPACE$

$NL \subsetneq NPSPACE$

Note that we know $PSPACE = NPSPACE$.

$P \subsetneq EXP$

$NP \subsetneq NEXP$

Note that we don't know if $EXP \subsetneq NEXP$.

Whether the other inclusions are strict, are still open problems. Even though there are no proofs, many, but not all, believe most of the inclusions to be strict.

Comment: Note that ​ NPSPACE = PSPACE . ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: True but I was using only space and time hierarchy theorems. And I did not mention NPSPACE in the inclusion list.

Comment: Anyway I have added a note that NPSPACE=PSPACE.